# Can't update Java in Visual Studio Code

Tags: java, visual-studio-code

I'm trying to update Java from 11 to 16 but it's saying the file locations doesn't have a folder, I have the correct update and the correct directory in java.home but it still says I'm on Java 11. I have tried uninstalling Visual Studio but it just reinstalls with the same settings.

Comment: How about CTRL + SHIFT + P and "Java: Configure Java Runtime" and chosse java version for each project or to vscode ( Java Tooling Runtime tab )

Comment: Run `java --version` and `where java` to check the existed jdk information.